# Gmail CTA Email Client Support

Tags: google-schemas

Can you please confirm if the Gmail One-Click / Go-To Action schemas should display fully within the native ioS mail client or the Gmail app itself? OR, do these only work fully on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

One click and go-to actions will display on mobile devices, however, they will only display with the Inbox app ([iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inbox-by-gmail-new-email-app/id905060486?mt=8)/ [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox&hl=en)).

Comment: Thanks for the response Franco. Is it likely the schemas will display within the native iOS Mail app or the Gmail app itself in the near future? This seems very limited with just the Inbox app being available which isn't too widely used..

Comment: I agree, it does seem limited. I haven't seen any news on action buttons integrating with the Gmail app. It looks like there's a lot of emphasis on Inbox per the Gmail blog (https://gmail.googleblog.com).